# Get rows where two values are unique to each other

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

The values of interest are an `EIN` and a registration number `REG`.
There are lots of records for each value.

What I want to know is which pair of values only appears with each other (or a blank `EIN`).

```
ID     EIN      REG
12     321      124
13     321      125
14     322      168
15     322      168
16     323      171
17     323      171
18     323
```

So in the above example, I'd want to select 322 and 168, as every time they appear, they appear together, but I also want to select 323 and 171, since they never appear with another value, just a non-value. 100% of records have an EIN, but a smaller portion have a Registration ID.

Any suggestions on how to query for this?

Comment: And your best effort at doing it yourself looks like . . .

Comment: I started to write it as a script pulling data from the database processing it and sending it back. I knew it had to be possible with the database instead, but really had no ideas. Hence the question.

Comment: Postgres version? Column types? Defined `NOT NULL`? "blank" is not possible with a numeric type. You'd have to have `NULL` values. Also: do you want all qualifying rows? With all columns? Or just one row per `(EIN, REG)` and what else to go with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of many possible ways:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ein, reg
FROM   test t
WHERE  reg is NOT NULL
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM test t1
   WHERE t1.ein = t.ein AND t1.reg <> t.reg
   OR    t1.reg = t.reg AND t1.ein <> t.ein);
```

```
ein | reg
----+-----
323 | 171
322 | 168
```

[**-> SQLfiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8db5e/25)

- I am assuming `EIN` is `NOT NULL`, but `REG` can be `NULL`, since you wrote:

> 100% of records have an EIN, but a smaller portion have a Registration ID.

- `NULL` never qualifies with the operator `<>`, so `(323, 171)` is not excluded.
- I exclude rows with reg `IS NULL` from the result, that seems to be your intention. So  `(323, NULL)` is not included.

Answer (score 5):

I got the results you were looking for using this query:

```
with cte as 
(
  select ein, count(distinct reg) as occ
    from test b    
    group by ein
    having count(distinct reg) = 1
)
select distinct t.ein, t.reg 
    from cte c 
    join test t 
      on c.ein = t.ein;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8db5e/12)

However, I'm sure there are other ways to do this.

Comment: This includes the row `(323, NULL)`. The Q is not very clear, but I collect from the free text it should be excluded.

Comment: @erwin I completely misunderstood.

Comment: I'd say, you very slightly misread a somewhat unclear question. :)